# How to install magento extension from .zip file?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-community

When I am try to install Magento extension from `.zip` file that time I have received some errors. Please suggest me what should I do to install it properly.

Comment: Can you put what errors you getting?

Comment: Which Magento version are you using ? Which errors do you get ? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Usually you can just unzip, but you should check that directory structure is Magento style, it at least should have app/code/ app/etc/modules directories

Comment: check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvqY3zhjF-c) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874761/installing-magento-plugins-without-using-magento-connect)

Answer (score 9):

**Follow bellow steps:**

**Step 1 :** Extract the ZIP-file locally and inspect the contents

Let's say we have an example ZIP-file called `AR_Example.zip` which contains a module name Example. The first step is to extract all files contained within the ZIP-file to your local computer. The extracted folder-structure could look a bit like this:

```
app/etc/modules/AR_Example.xml
app/code/community/AR/Example
```

If you cross-match these folders with the folders of the Magento filesystem, you can notice that Magento already contains these folders. We can copy all the files and folders recursively to Magento, so that for instance the new file `AR_Example.xml` is copied to the existing folder `app/etc/modules`.

When the folder-structure also contains a file called package.xml, there is chance that you can skip the procedure in this tutorial alltogether. Instead, login to your MagentoConnect Manager (within the Magento backend) and try to upload the ZIP-file as a package.

```
app/etc/modules/AR_Example.xml
app/code/community/AR/Example
package.xml
```

Some files might be contained in the ZIP-file but actually have little usage within the Magento filesystem. For instance, the file `package.xml` might be used by the MagentoConnect Manager, but it should not end up in the Magento root-folder. The same counts for files like installation.txt or README.txt or similar files.

**Step 2 :**  Disable the Magento Compiler

Magento has introduces a new feature called the Compiler, which allows you to merge all PHP-files into a single folder, which speeds up some of the PHP-functions that Magento uses. If you have enabled the Magento Compiler, make sure to disable it before making any changes. You can disable the Compiler through the Magento backend.

If you have not enabled the Compiler yet, do not just enable it to see what happens. It is a dangerous tool which could bring down your shop easily. Make sure you read all documentation concerning Magento performance before enabling the Compiler.
**Step 3 :**  Uploading all files to the Magento filesystem

Now you're ready to upload all files to the Magento root-filesystem. When you have SSH or SFTP available, it is best to use that - it gives you a secure encrypted connection to your Magento server. Alternatively use FTP, or control panels like CPanel or DirectAdmin.

**Step 4 :**  Refresh the Magento cache

The next step is to refresh the Magento cache. This can be done through the Magento backend. Instead of refreshing the Magento cache gently, we recommend you use the button Flush Cache to make sure all left-over files are gone.

Sometimes that's not even enough: If you are using Magento caching with default configuration-settings - meaning, the cache is stored in files - you can also try removing all the files from the Magento folder var/cache.

**Step 5 :**  Logout from the Magento backend

This step is important. Logout from the Magento backend. This makes you loose your PHP-session. Next, login again.

**Step 6 :**  Re-enable the Magento Compiler

If you had the Magento Compiler enabled before, and you disabled it in step 2, you can try to enable the Compiler again through the Magento backend. Make sure to rebuild the Compiler Cache, otherwise the new extension (or modified files) will not be included. Take note of all our warnings under step 2.

If things go wrong here, remove the file `includes/config.php`. This effectively disables the Compiler as well.
Success

Comment: Nice answer sir, very usefull information. + 1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Answer that @abdul gave was perfect, but wanted to share little script I put together so you don't have to manually copy each file across.

Using the command line you can just put the path of the zip file and your Magento install and its done instantly.

https://github.com/cameraki/Install-Magento-Extension-From-File